# How do I make combinations of words (ingredients) without repetition?

Tags: loops, combinations, combinatorics

Up front: I'm not a programmer! I have no programming experience. I'm a pastry cook. (But a quick learner!)

Basically, I'm trying to make a table of every possible combination of Flour, Water, Salt, Sugar, Eggs, Yeast, Butter, and Chemical Leaveners.

Right now, I have a list of 38 "building blocks" that are combinations of two of these things (i.e. "sugar/salt," "eggs/milk," "flour/yeast").

I want to take those small building blocks (plus individual ingredients, for odd numbers) and make groups of 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 that don't repeat and don't reuse ingredients (so "water-flour-salt-yeast" only comes out once, and not in any other order, and "water-flour-flour-water" isn't possible).

How would I go about doing this? I started with the combination generator at textmechanic.com, but there are too many repeated combinations/ingredients to manually sort through.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same way you'd do it by hand.  First ingredient plus each of the rest, then remove that ingredient from the list.  Second plus each of the rest (minus the first), remove from list.  Rinse, repeat.

Comment: @JBC Sure, yes...but how do I NOT do it by hand? (I started doing it by hand yesterday and the combinations add up quickly.)